# Javascript generate all numbers between 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

Well I searched up a lot about this but couldn't find anything with decent documentation on how it works If someone would please explain with an example how to do this that would be great

Comment: Use a [`for()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. There's not a lot to add to that, really, unless you can clearly explain where you're stuck?

Comment: Do you mean all integers between two integers?  (Not really all possible `Number` values between two Numbers, right?)

Comment: wonder if he's talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2a

Answer (score 8):

Iterate over all numbers between x and y, saving each to an array, then returning that array. Assuming x is less than y:

```
function getAllNumbersBetween(x, y) {
  var numbers = [];
  // Set a temporary variable i to start at value x.
  // As long as the value of i is less than the value y, increment it.
  // The loop will end when i is equal to y.
  for (var i = x; i < y; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}
```

For example:

```
getAllNumbersBetween(10, 15);  // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

If you want an inclusive range (10-15) you would change the loop condition to `i <= y`. If you want an exclusive range (11-14) you would change the loop iterator to `i = x + 1`.

---

I thought about this some more and came up with a solution that doesn't depend on parameters x and y with x strictly less than y. Also enforces the proper types of arguments. Also handles more than 2 arguments.

```
function getAllNumbersBetween() {
  var numbers = [];
  // Handle too few arguments.
  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    return numbers;
  }
  // Make sure x < y.
  Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments);
  // Assign each argument to a local variable.
  var x = arguments[0];
  var y = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
  // Make sure x and y are numbers.
  if (typeof x != 'number' || typeof y != 'number') {
    return numbers;
  }
  for (var i = x; i < y; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}
```

For example:

```
getAllNumbersBetween(15, 10);  // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
getAllNumbersBetween(15, 10, 11);  // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
getAllNumbersBetween(11, 15, 10);  // [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
getAllNumbersBetween(15);  // []
getAllNumbersBetween(15, '10');  // []
getAllNumbersBetween();  // []
```